# Trouble POSTing multiple related objects at once to api created with django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm making a ToDo app but having difficulties getting the api to allow a user to create a new list with multiple items via one api call.  Each list belongs to a specific "room".

I get 400 Bad Request.  If I leave the 'todo_items' off the POST data it works fine to create the ToDoList object.

Also, if I remove "user" from the Meta fields attribute for the CreateToDoItemSerializer, it'll create both the ToDoList object and the ToDoItem objects, but the "content" for each ToDoItem will be an empty string.  Inside the create method of NewToDoListSerializer, the validated_data is returning a list of empty OrderedDict() objects for the key "todo_items".  I'm not sure what to make of that.

my models:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="rooms")

class ToDoList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, related_name="todo_lists")
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="todo_lists")

class ToDoItem(models.Model):
    todo_list = models.ForeignKey(ToDoList, related_name="todo_items")
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="replies")
    content = FroalaField(options={'placeholder': '''Just start writing...
                                                 Highlight any text to bring up the editor.'''})
```

my serializers

```
class CreateTodoItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, read_only=False, queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = ToDoItem
        fields = ['pk', 'user', 'content']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        reply = ToDo.objects.create(**validated_data)


class NewToDoListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    room = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, read_only=False, queryset=Room.objects.all())
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    todo_items = CreateTodoItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ToDoList
        fields = ['pk', 'slug', 'title', 'user', 'room', 'todo_items']
        lookup_field = "slug"
        depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
        todo_items_data = validated_data.pop('todo_items')
        todo_list = ToDoList.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for todo_item_data in todo_items_data:
            todo_item = ToDo.objects.create(user=todo_list.user, todo_list=todo_list, **todo_item_data)
```

my viewset (the relevant bits):

```
class ToDoListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ToDoList.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ToDoListSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    renderer_classes = (renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer, renderers.JSONRenderer, renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer)
    template_name = "react_base.html"
    lookup_field = "slug"

def create(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.serializer_class = NewToDoListSerializer
    return super(ToDoListViewSet, self).create(request, **kwargs)

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    instance = serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

the data I'm POSTing:

todoListTitle, todoItemContent, moreTodoItemContent are all strings.  this.props.room.pk is an integer.  this.props.csrfmiddlewaretoken is the csrfmiddlewaretoken

```
var newToDoListData = {
        "room": this.props.room.pk,
        "title": todoListTitle,
        "todo_items": [{"content": todoItemContent}, {"content": moreTodoItemContent}],
        "csrfmiddlewaretoken": this.props.csrfmiddlewaretoken
    };
```

Comment: Have you attempted to remove the depth = 1 from the NewToDoListSerializer? I have a similar requirement and my def create() method looks very similar. If that works, then you can perhaps create a 'ListSerializer' that has depth = 1 for displaying the ToDoList, and the other serializer with the default depth.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately that had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the todo_items in your serializer required = false. I am not sure I understand what your second issue is.

```
class NewToDoListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
room = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, read_only=False, queryset=Room.objects.all())
user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
todo_items = CreateTodoItemSerializer(many=True, required=False)

class Meta:
    model = ToDoList
    fields = ['pk', 'slug', 'title', 'user', 'room', 'todo_items']
    lookup_field = "slug"
    depth = 1

def create(self, validated_data):
    todo_items_data = validated_data.pop('todo_items')
    todo_list = ToDoList.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for todo_item_data in todo_items_data:
        todo_item = ToDo.objects.create(user=todo_list.user, todo_list=todo_list, **todo_item_data)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with the above, it creates the ToDoItems but their content is always blank.

Comment: @KrisF - Sounds like it is a step in the right direction? The django create method is pretty standard, so it should work. Have you investigated the for loop to confirm that todo_item_data has the proper values that your model expects?

Comment: The problem isn't inside the create method.  It's prior to that somewhere in the validation process.  In the create method, todo_items_data is a list of empty OrderedDict objects, and thus each todo_item_data is an empty OrderedDict object.  Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: self.serializer_class = NewToDoListSerializer does nothing in your create method when you call super right after it.

Comment: What the actual data you are sending in the post? Mostly likely you aren't sending the json in the right format.